# Qt Model-View: What's the correct way to update the model and then the view when the data is stored and changed outside the model in a std::vector

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

I have subclassed a QTableModel and the data I want to be displayed is the contents of an std::vector which I keep a reference to in my model.
I have subclassed a QTableView to represent MyClass objects and display different properties of MyClass objects in different columns. 
Initially, I get exactly what I want to be displayed: the initialized std::vector and the 10 elements I put into it are displayed.
What I want to do after is add elements by means of other widgets to the std::vector and update the model and view accordingly. 
So I must somehow notify the model of the change and from what I have gathered from reading similar questions and Qt examples, it should be done like this: 
Before adding elements to the std::vector, I must first notify the model that I'm going to insert some rows. So what I did was create a member function in my model class that basically does this:

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), lastdisplayedrow, lastdisplayedrow+1);
myvector.push_back(myclassobject);
endInsertRows();
```

Since I didn't get the new element displayed, I decided that I also need to do something like this:

```
emit dataChanged(args_that_represent_the_new_row);
```

However, I can't get that new MyClass object to be displayed. 
And whatever the arguments in beginInsertRows, the new row is always appended at the end. What I mean by that is I can't get a new row in-between the already displayed rows even when I pass arguments like

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 1);
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Thank you **king_nak** for noticing the error, unfortunately the error was in my question and not my code. *lastdisplayedrow* is indeed the size of my vector.
My remaining question is (I leave room for the possibility that my approach is right I just messed up something in my code):
- Is this the correct approach to dealing with data that is stored outside the model?

### UPD

For anyone wondering: This seems like the correct approach to do this as I just managed to make it work. I'm going to give credit to **king_nak** for essentially finding what's wrong with the little snippet I provided. As for the real source of my problem: it was a dumb mistake on my part: when overriding rowCount I simply returned the value of my nRow member which had only been initialized in the constructor with myvector.size().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `beginInsertRows` seems to be incorrect:

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), lastdisplayedrow, 1);
```

This means you will insert rows in the span [`lastdisplayedrow`, `1`]. The parameters in this function specify the start- and end-index of the to be inserted rows (see [QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows)). Your call should look like this:

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), lastdisplayedrow, lastdisplayedrow + 1);
```

assuming that `lastdisplayedrow` equals your vector's size.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't near my code when I submitted this, the range I specified correctly. Is the unnamed QModelIndex() defaultly constructed the right way to do things? I couldn't understand what should be the parent in my case since it's a table and not a tree. Thank you for sparing time, I'll check my code to understand what might be the problem. But my overall approach is correct or is it fundamentally wrong? Because it's a read only tablemodel and I didn't want to go with a convenience class, but couldn't find any examples similar enough to mine. Thanks again

Comment: According to [this article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-classes), the invalid `QModelIndex()` is correct. It denotes the invisible root for table models (see section "Rows and columns")